# cpanm does not register all installed modules in perllocal.pod

Tags: perl, cpanm, perldoc

According to [CPAN Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html):

> Each time a module is installed on your system, it appends information
>   to a file called `perllocal.pod`

I have installed several CPAN modules using `cpanm`, the problem is that  some modules do not get registered in `perllocal.pod`. For example, I have installed [String::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Escape), [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote), and [String::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Util) using `cpanm`. If I type

```
$ perldoc -u perllocal | grep String::
```

I get output:

```
=head2 Tue Apr 21 16:47:34 2015: C<Module> L<String::Escape|String::Escape>
=head2 Thu Aug  6 18:51:04 2015: C<Module> L<String::ShellQuote|String::ShellQuote>
```

Note that `String::Util` is missing, even if all three modules are installed under directory `/home/hakon/perl5/lib/perl5/`. For example, if I type:

```
$ perldoc -l String::Util
```

I get output:

```
/home/hakon/perl5/lib/perl5/String/Util.pod
```

Note: The problem is not related to `perldoc`. The `perldoc` command simply displays the Pod in the file `perllocal.pod`:

```
$ perldoc -l perllocal
/home/hakon/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
```

Since this file does not contain any Pod for `String::Util`, it is likely that the problem is that `cpanm` did not register it ( for some unknown reason ) when I installed the module.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fault of the [Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/source/MIKO/String-Util-1.24/Makefile.PL) in String::Util; by using an intermediary variable in WriteMakefile it thwarts the parsing in App::cpanminus.

I suggest you log this as a [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=String-Util) -- it has an easy fix: simply don't use the variable.