# Is this Perl module installed (and where) or not?

Tags: perl, debian, perl-module, bugzilla, plasticscm

I have recently upgrade bugzilla [on  Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.3 (squeeze)] (to the latest version and although it seems to work, I have an external script for integrating it with PlasticSCM source control which gives out the following error:

```
Can't locate Email/Sender/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 27.
```

The stack trace keeps going all the way up to my custom script. but I think it is not relevant.

Line 27 in Bugzilla/Mailer.pm says:

```
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
```

And I assumed that the problem was that
Thinking that the issue was that the module Email::Sender::Simple was missing.

Bugzilaa has a script called `./checksetup.pl` that is used for checking that all the prerequirements are met. When I am trying to run this script it does not indicate anything missing.

However, when it Does find missing libraries it gives instructions to add them using the a command with the structure:

```
 /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl HTML::FormatText::WithLinks
```

So I executed:

```
 /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::Sender:Simple
```

Which said:

```
Checking for                 CPAN (v1.81)     ok: found v1.9402
Checking for                 YAML (any)       ok: found v1.15
Checking for   ExtUtils-MakeMaker (v6.31)     ok: found v7.1
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/MYUSERNAME/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 30 Nov 2015 07:17:02 GMT
Installing Email::Sender:Simple version 1.300021...
Email::Sender::Simple is up to date (1.300021).
```

So it looks like it installed the module but running the CGI script again results in exactly the same stack trace.

Also running the `install-module.pl` script again returns the same result again (as if it has just installed it again...).

How can I tell If this module is installed (and where) or not and what can I do to make my script work?

**UPDATE**:
I think i know where the problem is.
The cgi script that I am trying to run has the following line for its first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
```

from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2526809/25412
I understand that the T flag causes `.` not to be part of @INC (i.e. Perls module search path) so this is why the `lib` folder that my bugzilla's installation folder (which is also where the cgi is) is not used and the file lib/Email/Sender/Simple.pm that is inside it is being ignored by the CGI.

So **the updated Q** is - should I:
1. Remove the `T` from the first line of the cgi? or
2. Somehow (and how?) install EMAIL::Sender::Simple to some other location that is a part of the @INC ?

I tend think the answer should be the 2 beacuse I think the T flag is there for some security reasons because [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A-T%2A) says :

> "It's a good idea to turn them on explicitly for programs that run on
>   behalf of someone else whom you might not necessarily trust, such as
>   CGI programs or any internet servers you might write in Perl."

Comment: What is that `install-module.pl` file? Never seen that before. In debian, you would use apt-get, I suspect. E.g. `apt-get install libfoo-perl`. Or use the cpan utility `cpan Email::Sender::Simple`. And of course, you'd need to install as the correct user with reference to where your perl program is looking.

Comment: I am not a Perl person in any way, the `install-module.pl` is part of bugzilla. when running bugzillas `./checksetup.pl` script  if it finds missing modules it shows command to execute in order to install them. those commands have the form `/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::Sender:Simple`.

Comment: You probably have PERL5LIB set in one environment, but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can check module's installation path using this command:

```
perldoc -l Email::Sender::Simple
```

If it is not install it will give the below output:

```
No documentation found for "Email::Sender::Simple".
```

Else it will give the full path of that module.

Comment: Note, due to some bugs, some installed modules could not get registered. See [cpanm does not register all installed modules in perllocal.pod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679413/cpanm-does-not-register-all-installed-modules-in-perllocal-pod)

Comment: trying to run this I get `You need to install the perl-doc package to use this program.`.

Comment: @epeleg: `apt-get install perl-doc`

Comment: `perldoc -l Email::Sender::Simple` returns
`No documentation found for "Email::Sender::Simple"`.

so the Q remains why does install-module.pl thinks its installed...
and how can I convince it to uninstall or reinstall...

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, `perldoc -l` doesn't use perllocal.

Comment: @epeleg: What is install-module.pl file? You are not very clear with your question. Show us how and where you are using this module and what errors/warnings you are getting. That might be helpful for us and you.

Comment: I have explained that in one of the comments on the Question. I have now edited the Q to better explain. and also added an update about new things I learned.